# JNI - make an instance of another C++ class

Tags: java, c++, object, java-native-interface

I have an old application (C++) which I want to invoke with java via JNI.
So I read some tutorials and the basics (call a method in C++ from Java) worked very well.

But now my problem is I want to instance another C++ object in the method, which is used by JNI. Is this principally not possible or is there any way to do this?

For explanation:

This is my Java-Class helloworld.java which calls the native method 'callnative()'

```
public class helloworld{
  private native void callnative();

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new helloworld().callnative();

  }

  static {
     System.loadLibrary("helloworld");
  }
}
```

This is the native method java_helloworld_callnative(..)

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "helloworld.h"
#include "hellouniverse.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_helloworld_callnative(JNIEnv *env,
                                              jobject obj)
{
  printf("HelloWorld\n");
  hellouniverse *h = new hellouniverse();
  h->printHelloUniverse();
  return;
}
```

This is the class hellouniverse

```
#include "hellouniverse.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

hellouniverse::hellouniverse(){ 
}

void hellouniverse::printHelloUniverse(){
  printf("HelloUniverse!!\n");
}
```

I compiled helloworld.cpp with:

g++ -fPIC -shared -I$JAVA_PATH/include -I$JAVA_PATH/include/linux/ -o libhelloworld.so hellworld.cpp

and hellouniverse.cpp with:

g++ -c -o hellouniverse.o hellouniverse.cpp

When I run java helloworld the output is:

HelloWorld
java:symbol lookup error: $./libhelloworld.so: undefined symbol: _ZN13hellouniverseC1Ev

I hope you can help me with my Problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to link the `hellouniverse` stuff into the library. For example

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -I$JAVA_PATH/include -I$JAVA_PATH/include/linux/ -o libhelloworld.so hellworld.cpp hellouniverse.cpp
```

Or

```
g++ -fPIC -I $JAVA_PATH/include -I$JAVA_PATH/include/linux -c helloworld.cpp
g++ -fPIC -I $JAVA_PATH/include -I$JAVA_PATH/include/linux -c hellouniverse.cpp
g++ -fPIC -shared -o libhelloworld.so helloworld.o hellouniverse.o
```

Consider using a Makefile to automate this.